# How to force evaluation of type annotations from a different module?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I've been using Python's type annotations in an unusual way: I have some code that inspects the annotations of a function's arguments at run-time, searches for values that match the types of the arguments, and calls the function with values of appropriate types (if found).

This has been working wonderfully, and was remarkably easy to implement, but the source file has grown fairly large, so today I tried breaking it into multiple files. I found that `get_type_hints()` can't evaluate a type annotation if it's from a module other than the current one, at least not without being given a global namespace where all the needed types are defined.

I'm using `from __future__ import annotations` everywhere, so the type annotations in each function's `.__annotations__` attribute are stored as strings in need of evaluation. To evaluate them, I need the globals from the module where the function was defined. How can I get that? Or will that even work? I'm using `if TYPE_CHECKING:` to avoid circular imports; consequently some annotations won't be available at run-time in each module where they're applied to a function.

Here's the code that extracts the types of the function arguments, if that helps:

```
def params_of(func: Callable) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, TypeAnnotation]]:
    type_hints = get_type_hints(func)
    for param_name in inspect.signature(func).parameters:
        if param_name == 'return':
            continue  # disregard return type
        yield (param_name, type_hints.get(param_name, Any))
```

(`TypeAnnotation` is only for readability; it's defined to `Any`.)

Comment: On Python 3.10 you could try `inspect.get_annotations`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.get_annotations

Comment: @pawamoy Thanks! I haven't tried Python 3.10 yet. I'll check this out.